# Number Formatting from $100000 to $100 000,00

Tags: number-formatting

Can someone please help format this number: `$100000` to `$100 000,00`. (in words: Hundred Thousand dollars) or if million it must format `$100000` to `$1 000 000,00`

I only know of the standard .NET decimal.ToString( "N2" ) e.g.

```
decimal number = 1000000d;
string formatedNumber = number.ToString( "N2" ); // This will give you 1,00,000.00
```

Is there a standard .NET format I can re-use or will I have to create my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        decimal number = 1000000;
        Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("C"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")); // 1 000.000,00
```

'C' stands for currency, so yes, there is a standard format for it.

Comment: number.ToString("C") gives me the exact results as number.ToString("NS"), only adds the default computer currency (Locale)

Comment: How about using `ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))`?